# How can select different records from a list with duplicated values?

Tags: sql, oracle, select

I'm new in the SQL/Oracle universe and I would like to ask for your help. This is a very simple question that I'm stuck in.

So, let me give you a picture. I have a regular table, let's call it "table1". The PK is the first column, "c1". Let's suppose that I would like to make the following `select`:

```sql
select (1) from table1 where c1 in ('1','2','3')
```

This will give me

|  | (1) |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 1 |

However, if I make the following `select`

```
select (1) from table1 where c1 in ('1','2','2')
```

this will give me

|  | (1) |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 |

My question is, why in the second case there is not 3 records? Can I modify the second case to give 3 records, in other words, how can I prevent to the selection acts like a "distinct" clause?

I know that it may be a dummy question, so let me thank you all in advance.

Comment: `where c1 in ('1','2','2')` is syntactic shorthand for `WHERE ( c1 = '1' OR c1 = '2' OR c1 = '2' )` which semantically the same as `WHERE ( c1 = '1' OR c1 = '2' )`.

Comment: Thanks by the explanation!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `where` clause filters rows generated by the `from` clause.

Conditions in the `where` clause only specify whether or not a given row is in the result set.  They do not specify how many times a given row is in the result set.

If you want to "multiply" the number of rows, you would need to use a `join` with a derived table that has duplicate values.

Comment: Thanks you by the directions! It's now clear what I must do in the logic.